# Make .jmx file to open by default (double click on file) with jmeter GUI on windows 10

Tags: windows, jmeter, open-with

I'm trying to make my windows 10 to open .jmx file with jmeter GUI when I double click on it.

I' using "apache-jmeter-3.2" and currently, in order to open a jmx file I am opening the jmeter jar "\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\ApacheJMeter.jar" and then dragging the jmx file into it.

I have tried to use the "open with" windows feature, but if i navigate to the jar location and mark "show all files" in order to see .jar extenstions and select it, it show me a windows message says "this app cannot run on your PC".

Answer (score 5):

You should use [jmeter-t.cmd](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running) (found in JMeter's bin folder)

> drop a JMX file on this to load it in GUI mode

Associate file extension `.jmx` to this command to open JMeter GUI on double click JMeter file.

Comment: worked. but is there a way to do it without that cmd window in background ?

Comment: @Amitk `jmeter-n.cmd` is for non GUI, `jmeterw.cmd` for opening JMeter without console window

Comment: opening jmx with  jmeter-t.cmd opens both gui and cmd in background, using jmeterw doesnt open anything.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use [Assoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/assoc) command to set file type association for JMeter .jmx scripts

   ```
   Assoc .jmx=jmeter
   ```
2. Use [FType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ftype) command to define JMeter executable for the .jmx scripts

   ```
   FType jmeter="c:\apps\jmeter\bin\jmeter-t.cmd" %1
   ```

   [image]
3. That's it, you should be now able to open .jmx scripts by double clicking them on Windows. Just in case here is [how to configure MacOS for automatically opening JMeter scripts](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-open-jmx-files-on-a-mac-in-1-double-click)
4. According to [JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider migrating to JMeter 5.0 (or whatever is the current version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)

Comment: Worth noting that you should put quotes around %1 in the FType command if you want to double-click a jmx file from a directory with spaces in the path, otherwise you will get the slightly cryptic error message: "Please supply a script name with the extension .jmx"