# Prevent JMeter from creating run log file when opening a test on Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have followed the instructions from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53955919/5012320) which causes JMeter to be opened when double clicking on a .jmx file in Windows.

The problem is that when I open a .jmx file by double clicking on the file it automatically creates a JMeter log file (and names it `[name_of_jmx_file].log`, regardless of if you do anything with the test. The file is also not removed once you close JMeter, so I have to manually delete it each time.

This appears to be caused by the `-j` param in the following line from the default `jmeter-t.cmd` file:

```
call "%~dp0"jmeter -j "%~n1.log" -t "%~nx1" %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Simply removing `-j "%~n1.log"` doesn't  prevent the creation of the logfile as JMeter still creates the file and just defaults the name of the file to `jmeter.log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround which simply puts these auto-generated log files into a specific folder which I just periodically delete. This prevents the file from getting created in the same directory as the script which was the main inconvenience, though ideally I would like to figure out how to prevent the creation of this file entirely.

My workaround was to change the following line of the jmeter-t.cmd file:

```
call "%~dp0"jmeter -j "%~n1.log" -t "%~nx1" %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

To this:

```
call "%~dp0"jmeter -j "C:\Users\[WINDOWS_USER]\Documents\JMeterRunLogs\%~n1.log" -t "%~nx1" %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `log4j2.xml` file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, if you look for this line:

```
<File name="jmeter-log" fileName="${sys:jmeter.logfile:-jmeter.log}" append="false">
```

and change `${sys:jmeter.logfile:-jmeter.log}` to

```
C:\Users\[WINDOWS_USER]\Documents\JMeterRunLogs\jmeter.log
```

JMeter log file will always be generated under that folder no matter where you launch JMeter from.

More information:

- [Log4j - Log4j 2 Appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html), pay attention to **FileAppender**
- [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)

Comment: That is helpful, but what if I just want to make it not generate a log file anywhere? Or at least remove the log file[s] as soon as I close Jmeter